# Maximizing Adobe Air windows on multiple monitors

Tags: javascript, air, multiple-monitors

In an Adobe Air AJAX application with multiple windows running on a system with multiple (three or more) monitors, can you maximize the windows in each monitor? I've seen posts by others trying to do this, but I've not seen anyone saying how it worked out.

I basically need to build a 'status monitor' system (similar to, say, an airport departures monitor) in which there are public-facing displays that need to look and feel like single-purpose, embedded applications -- no window chrome and no visible desktop. I don't think this should be any different from any other windows application, but I don't know about Air. I have a dual-monitor Mac setup right now, but I can't easily test Windows and I likely will never be able to test three monitors at once.

This application will be run as an AJAX Air application written in Aptana (or DW if it makes a difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be possible, but might require a fair amount of work. First, take a look to [Screen.screens](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Screen.html#screens), that returns an array with all the screens available in the system.

Then is when the work starts as you have to consider things like:

> Note that there is not necessarily a
>   one-to-one correspondance between
>   screens and the physical monitors
>   attached to a computer. For example,
>   two monitors may display the same
>   screen.

HTH,

Juan

Comment: Right. Perfect. That actually makes a lot of sense. It looks like this property is exposed to JavaScript via `air.Screen`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have saw an interesting application developed for Christian Cantrell, and i think he uses some type of "resize feature".. it's totally functional.. take a look to iReversi application written in as3 (air/flash)

take a look this video:
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/04/one_application_five_screens.html

find source code in "github dot com / cantrell / Reversi"